# Android popwindow style full screen

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen, popupwindow

I have an activity to be pop up.
Here's the xml code for activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pop_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#88e8e8e8"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/popwindow_selector"
        android:text="@string/take_photo"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_album"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/popwindow_selector"
        android:text="@string/from_album"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/popwindow_selector"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the style  for activity like

```
 <style name="activityBottom" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AnimBottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>

</style>
```

the main.xml code

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.jouhu.wwwq.AddPicturePopActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/activityBottom" >
    </activity>
```

but the pop up activity width can't be full screen.

Answer (score 0):

To display activity as a pop up , you can apply themes related to *dialog* to your activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** file. for example

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.jouhu.wwwq.AddPicturePopActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>
```

or

```
android:theme=@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog"
```

etc...

Comment: my application is build base android 2.3.so  may be I better to write a style,and the question is since android 4.0, it's width can't be full screen. it's perplex me for a long time.